# Need help understanding the proof of theorem related to Nielsen Transformation.

Tags: group-theory

> Book: Introduction to group theory by Oleg Bogopolski
>
> Theorem 1.2: Any finite tuple $U = \{u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_m\}$ of elements of a free group $F$ can be carried into a Nielsen reduced tuple $V$ by a finite number of Nielsen transformations.

**Part of proof that is confusing me**: If the condition (N1) is not satisfied, we can decrease the number of elements of U by using the transformation (T3). Suppose that the condition (N2) is not
satisfied. Using (T1), we may assume that v1,v2 $\in$ U. If, say |v1v2| < |v1|, then using (T2), we can replace v1 by v1v2.

In the above snippet of proof, I understand the part the if (N1) is not satisfied we can use (T3). But then if (N2) is not satisfied then it is not clear why we use (T1).

Please refer to the [image] for more info about T1 T2 N1 N2 terminology.

Thankyou.

Comment: "But then if (N3) is not satisfied then it is not clear why we use (T1)." Is your snipped missing a bit? There is no statement "Suppose that the condition (N3) is not satisfied" in your quote.

Comment: (Also, I don't understand "...we may assume that v1; v2 2 U". Possibly you would benefit from [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/10513) MathJax tutorial?)

Comment: I wrote all this in a hurry! I missed that thankyou for pointing out.

Comment: You're still missing the bit about (N3). There is no (N3) in your quote!

Comment: I just want to know this much, for the time being and N3 is a distinct case therefore might ask about that later . But before I want to know the consequence of N2 CONDITION

Comment: So what's your question? (Currently it makes no sense, as there is no (N3) in your quote.)